# Holding spacebar causes mouse cursor to disappear

Tags: javascript, scroll, dom-events, keyboard-events

My web app has keyboard shortcuts that involve holding the space bar. The problem is that the mouse cursor disappears when the space bar is held. I think what's happening is that the browser is trying to scroll down (even though in my case there's never anything to scroll down to). If the user moves the mouse cursor while holding the space bar, the cursor flickers into view, only to disappear again when the mouse has stopped moving. Once the user releases the space bar, the mouse cursor stay hidden, until the mouse is moved again, after which the cursor stays visible. This happens in Chrome, Safari, Opera (webkit/blink).

Among many things, I've tried the canonical solution of `preventDefault()` on the event, which doesn't work, regardless of where I listen. Clearly, this is possible, because I've used apps before that employ the space bar to do something other than scroll down.

```
var html = document.documentElement;
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log("document keydown");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log("window keydown");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

html.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log("html keydown");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

body.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    console.log("body keydown");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});


document.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    console.log("document keypress");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

window.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    console.log("window keypress");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

html.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    console.log("html keypress");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

body.addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    console.log("body keypress");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note: My app is always exactly 100% of the viewport. There is never any reason to scroll, which is why I am comfortable with the idea of overriding the convention.

Any help very appreciated.

Comment: Does the same happen when you press a different key?

Comment: yes, it happens with any key. E.g. I click on the margin of this very SO page in Chrome, press the space bar, and the cursor disappears until I move the mouse again.

Comment: You may be SOL on this, I think you're encountering browser functionality.  Even on sites like JIRA that use keyboard shortcuts (like 'e' to edit the description), the mouse still disappears whenever any key is pressed.

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to work around this issue? I'm trying to building similar functionality (hold space to temporary switch to another tool), but it only works with modifier keys.

Answer (score 0):

TL/DR: apply `overflow: hidden` style on document.body.

---

I just found this unanswered (!!) question here after same problem, but in 5 min found my solution.

Several years of no answer so I'll explain my own situation too since it must be a rare context.

**My scenario:** Developing full-page graphic app using PIXI, along with overlaid HTML DOM elements.  Using Safari on MacBook Pro.

**Interest:** press spacebar to interact with PIXI content

**Approach:** use a state tracking variable using **keydown** and **keyup** listeners. Press spacebar, in keydown update the `cursor` style when the event target is the document.body.  Likewise revert `cursor` style in keyup.

**Problem:** the browser wants to scroll.  Even when using `event.preventDefault`.

I never use spacebar to scroll a page, so I was entirely blind to the existing browser behaviour.

**Discovery:** Experimenting on other pages, including here on the SO question, I found the cursor ceases to be hidden on spacebar press when at bottom of the page.  So I know the browser is considering the body length...

**Solution:** apply `overflow: hidden` style on document.body.

Now I know for various applications this may not suffice, but it DOES SOLVE THIS PROBLEM for me. The browser knows there is zero overflow processing on the body, so spacebar is inert for scrolling.

After applying this, overflow elsewhere still works: other divs of the web app can still scroll, with assigned dimensions.